# Find permutations in a symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

In the symmetric group $S_{12}$ we have the permutations:

$$\sigma=
        \begin{bmatrix}
          1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
          8 & 5 & 3 & 12 & 10 & 4& 7 &1 & 6  & 2  & 11   & 9  
       \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\tau=
        \begin{bmatrix}
          1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
          11 & 7 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 8& 2 &12 & 6  & 10  & 3   & 9 
       \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\theta=
        \begin{bmatrix}
          1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
          7 & 12 & 11 & 2 & 10 & 8& 4 &5 & 3  & 6  & 9   & 1 
       \end{bmatrix}$$

Find, if exist, permutations $ρ_1$ and $ρ_2$, so that $\tau = ρ_1\sigmaρ_1^{-1}$ and $\theta=ρ_2\sigma ρ_2^{-1}$.

I think $ρ_2$ doesn't exist but I can't explain why (probably because of the row of the disjoint cycle?). And how can I find the permutation $ρ_1$?

[image]

Comment: Have you written these permutations in cycle notation?

Comment: Yes. I have written them in cycle notation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> Two elements of $S_n$ are conjugate to each other iff they are of the same cycle type, i.e. they have same number of cycles of each length.

Suppose $\alpha,\beta$ are of the same cycle type. Then $$\alpha=(a_1\dots a_{n_1})(b_1\dots b_{n_2})\dots(x_1\dots x_{n_k}) $$
and $$\beta=(a'_1\dots a'_{n_1})(b'_1\dots b'_{n_2})\dots(x'_1\dots x'_{n_k})$$
Define $\gamma\in S_n$ where $a_i\mapsto a'_i ,\dots,x_i\mapsto x'_i$.
Check that $\beta=\gamma\alpha\gamma^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I find ρ1(1),  ρ1(2),...?

Comment: @Elena In your case, write $\sigma=(1 ,8)(2, 5, 10)(4 ,12, 9 ,6)$ and $\tau=(2, 7)(1, 11 ,3)(6, 8 ,12 ,9)$. Define $\rho_1\in S_{12}$ where $1\mapsto 2, 8\mapsto 7, 2\mapsto 
 1,\dots,6 \mapsto 9$.